Question migration
Since we have finally graduated, it seems like we should be eligible for question migration paths with the rest of the SE network (see here).
However, it seems to me like when trying to migrate an off-topic question the only allowed path still is Quantitative Finance Meta. 
When will that change?

These paths can be proposed by the community and need to be enabled manually by Stack Exchange. 
Paraphrasing communication with Stack Exchange:

Once that (Quant.SE graduates) happens we can evaluate the need for migration paths, either to CV or elsewhere on the network. Note that migration paths have to be approved--a demonstrated high volume of posts migrated and a low rejection rate generally lead to that approval.

I'm not aware of any rejections of migrations to Stats so I'd say this proposal makes a decent chance. I'll talk to Stack Exchange directly too.

Thanks Bob, this addresses my concerns.

You're welcome. ICYMI http://meta.quant.stackexchange.com/q/1516/848
